# Sample larger than population Python

Tags: python, random

I need a list containing integers with cardinality nlittle that have to be random in (valuemin,value) but I got the error sample larger than population running the code below

```
    nlittle=random.randrange(5,15)
    value=random.randint(1,100)
    valuemin=int(valore*0.8)
    minmoduniform=5*valoremin
    maxmoduniform=20*valore
    puniform=random.sample(xrange(valuemin,value), nlittle)
    rouniform=random.sample(xrange(valuemin,value), nlittle)
```

How can I solve this problem and print a list if nlittle (in my code) is bigger than the difference in xrange?
Ty

Comment: "print a list" containing what? Your problem is that you are trying to get for example a sample of size 10 from a list of length 5, which is impossible. What is your original goal?

Comment: I need a list containing integers with cardinality nlittle that have to be random in (valuemin,value) @Jasper

Comment: then you should rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rands = [random.randint(valuemin, value) for x in xrange(nlittle)]
```

this picks `nlittle` integers between `valuemin` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

// To get cardinality

I agree with @Jasper. Rephrase your question.

a possible solution might be to use,

```
n= xrange(valuemin,value)
m= xrange(valuemin,value)
puniform=random.sample(n, min(len (n) ,nlittle))
rouniform=random.sample(m, min(len(m) ,nlittle))
```

// See why your code might be going wrong.

Your snippet of code might run into trouble at multiple instances.

Lets take a case.

nlittle is a random integer between 5 and 15. say it were were 15
value is between 0 to 100. say it has been assigned 3.
Hopeing, valuemin were less than three say 1. ( I could not be sure as I don't know about valoremin)

you were trying to get a sample of 15 objects from a list of 2 objects which gave you the error.

see the documentatoin for random library here. it would be more helpful
https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

I am adding an extract from the website for random.sample(pop,k) here below.

> random.sample(population, k)
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements
>   chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without
>   replacement.
>
> New in version 2.3.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while
>   leaving the original population unchanged. The resulting list is in
>   selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random
>   samples. This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned
>   into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).
>
> Members of the population need not be hashable or unique. If the
>   population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible
>   selection in the sample.
>
> To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an xrange() object as
>   an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling
>   from a large population: sample(xrange(10000000), 60).